# C program runs in Cygwin but not Linux (Malloc)

Tags: c, gdb, malloc, valgrind

I have a heap allocation error that I cant spot in my code that is picked up on vanguard/gdb on Linux but runs perfectly on a Windows cygwin environment.  I understand that Linux could be tighter with its heap allocation than Windows but I would really like to have a response that discovers the issue/possible fix.  I'm also aware that I shouldn't typecast malloc in C but it's a force of habit and doesn't change my problem from happening.  My program actually compiles without error on both Linux & Windows but when I run it in Linux I get a scary looking result:

> malloc.c:3074: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
>   Aborted

Attached snippet from my code that is being pointed to as the error for review:

```
/* Main */

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    FILE *pFile;  
    unsigned char *buffer;  
    long int lSize;  

    pFile = fopen ( argv[1] , "r" );
    if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error on arg[1]",stderr); return 1;}

    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * lSize+1);
    if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); return 2;}

    bitpair * ppairs = (bitpair *) malloc(sizeof(bitpair) * (lSize+1));

    //line 51 below
    calcpair(ppairs, (lSize+1));

    /* irrelevant stuff */

    fclose(pFile);
    free(buffer);
    free(ppairs);  
}

typedef struct {  
long unsigned int a;  //not actual variable names...  Yes I need them to be long unsigned  
long unsigned int b;  
long unsigned int c;  
long unsigned int d;  
long unsigned int e;  
} bitpair;  

void calcpair(bitpair * ppairs, long int bits);

void calcPairs(bitpair * ppairs, long int bits) {

    long int i, top, bot, var_1, var_2;
    int count = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < bits; i++) {

        top = 0;

        ppairs[top].e = 1;

        do {
            bot = count;
            count++;
        } while(ppairs[bot].e != 0);

        ppairs[bot].e = 1;

        var_1 = bot;
        var_2 = top;

        bitpair * bp = &ppairs[var_2];
        bp->a = var_2;
        bp->b = var_1;
        bp->c = i;

        bp = &ppairs[var_1];
        bp->a = var_2;
        bp->b = var_1;
        bp->c = i;

    }

    return;
}
```

gdb reports: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000603290 *

valgrind reports the following message 5 times before exiting due to "VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR" signal 11 (SIGSEGV):
Invalid read of size 8
==2727==    at 0x401043: calcPairs (in /home/user/Documents/5-3/ubuntu test/main)
==2727==    by 0x400C9A: main (main.c:51)
==2727==  Address 0x5a607a0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Comment: I think you left out the interesting part.. what happens in calcpair()?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've updated the OP to include the snippet of calcpair().  'buffer' is used to perform an iterative fread on a second file 1 byte at a time:
fread (buffer,1,1,pFile);

Comment: excuse, the iterative fread is on the same file opened in the OP (pFile).

Comment: Is this your complete `calcPairs` function or only a snippet?  If this is the whole thing, then you have several problems, not the least of which is the `do {...} while` loop's ability to run past the end of the array.

Comment: It's a snippet, but mostly of where the action is. Suggestion to fix?

Comment: @Shawn- You never define your loop condition `cs`.  After the existing code in your `do` loop, you need to check the value of `count` and abort if `count >= bits` (jump out of the outer loop too).

Comment: @bta- The 'cs' in the for loop should be 'bits', typo in translating.  I'll add a check on count. thanks.

Comment: I suspect it's not related to your problem since it works on Windows but not Linux, but `ftell` does not return a meaningful value on a text-mode stream.  Its result can be used only by `fseek`.  If you want to calculate the number of bytes, you should open the stream in binary mode.

Comment: If you want diagnostic help, put up your whole source on a web site and link to it.  If you don't have your own site,http://pastebin.com is a good place (but not archival).

Comment: Compile your source with `-g` to get debugging information - that'll make the valgrind output more useable.

Answer (score 1):

At a wild guess ftell is returning -1 and malloc doesn't like being asked to allocate zero bytes. The behaviour of malloc(0) is implementation dependent in C.

Comment: I can confirm through test that it is lSize is being handed the proper size, 27 in this case (sometimes much much larger, hence the need for long).

Comment: It's implementation-dependent, but it has to return a pointer value that you can safely pass to `free()` (including `NULL`).  It's not allowed to abort.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are expecting malloc to return pre-zeroed memory.

```
    do {
        bot = count;
        count++;
    } while(ppairs[bot].e != 0);
```

could easily get to the end of your ppairs without finding a zeroed ppairs[bot].e

You want to use calloc instead of malloc, that clears the memory before returning it.

```
bitpair * ppairs = (bitpair *) calloc(sizeof(bitpair) * (lSize+1));
```

Comment: This helped although you didn't call calloc correctly (needs 2 arguments):  void * calloc ( size_t num, size_t size );  


When I use calloc with lSize+1 as num and the argument above as the size I can run against small target files, but larger ones (40KB) generate the Memory Error from if(ppairs==NULL).

Comment: Possibly easier than using `calloc` is keeping your current `malloc` calls and using `memset` to zero them out after they are allocated.

Comment: I dont have experience with memset but doing: 
memset (ppairs, 0, lSize+1); 
along with malloc on ppairs compiles but still gives the same heap error

Comment: memset (ppairs, 0, sizeof(bitpair) * (lSize+1));

Comment: @aspo- Still gives the malloc issue at run-time

Comment: @Shawn - but I suspect it fixes the Valgrind error you were seeing.  Judging from the mistakes in the code you've shown, I suspect you are writing to unmalloced memory somewhere else in the "irrelevant stuff".    That can end up overwriting data structures that malloc uses which will cause badness later on.

Answer (score 1):

### Looks Like An Array Overrun

Nothing is keeping this loop from overrunning the end of the ppair array:

```
    do { 
        bot = count; 
        count++; 
    } while(ppairs[bot].e != 0);
```

Especially since this line will overwrite your terminating zero:

```
ppairs[bot].e = 1;
```

Try this instead:

```
    do { 
        bot = count; 
        count++; 
    } while((bot < bits) && (ppairs[bot].e != 0));
```

Yours,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Your second call to `malloc` never has its return value checked.  Modify it so it looks more like the first one, as in:

```
bitpair * ppairs = (bitpair *) malloc(sizeof(bitpair) * (lSize+1));
if (ppairs == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); free(buffer); return 3;}
```

Also, remember `malloc` expects a `size_t` (the definition of which is implementation-dependent) for an argument.  Make sure that when you pass `(sizeof(bitpair) * (lSize+1))` to `malloc`, you are not overflowing a `size_t` (if `size_t` is defined as `unsigned int`, you could run into problems since `lSize` is a `long`).

Comment: Thanks, I did forget to do that.  Unfortunately that the malloc issue remains

Comment: Changing lSize and associated variables in function to regular int resulted in the same run-time error

Comment: Random thoughts (may or may not change anything):  Instead of declaring `ppairs` in the same line where you call `malloc`, declare it at the top of the function.  Also, try moving the definition of `bitpair` up above your `main` function.